# How to pause mocked service with Observable on demand in Angular tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, observable

I am creating a simple mock service. In some tests, it needs to emit 1 value, in others I need it to fire 2 values (depending on "route changes").

How do I tell the observable when to shoot the next value? Example service:

```
class MockService {
  getThings() {
    return Observable.of(value1, value2);
  }
}
```

My component subscribes to this in ngOnInit, so since it's a subscription, it consumes both values at once. I've tried things like manually creating Observable in the mock service constructor, but I cannot get the observer to trigger next value when needed.